# Is it possible to update more than 60 times per second with the XNA 4.0 Game class?

Tags: c#, xna-4.0

I'm having a problem with timing in XNA 4.0, writing in C# and using Visual Studio 2010 express.

I'm not writing a game exactly, but I'm trying to use XNA for it's simplified content pipeline, drawing, and timing. What I'm trying to do is write a program that can time a user's response to onscreen stimuli at very fine resolutions - less than 5 ms, ideally.

To do this, I need to call the update routine (so I can poll the keyboard) no less than once every 5 ms. Even in variable step timing, I can't get the timing below about 16 ms per call. This doesn't appear to have anything to do with the amount of processing that I do in my update and draw routines. I can comment out everything in both routines and the program still spends roughly 16.66 ms on each iteration.

In fixed step timing, I can set the target to about 60 iterations per second (16.66 ms between updates), but if I try to go any faster than that, the IsRunningSlowly flag is tripped, and the game seems to try to compensate - several iterations will run faster than 60 iterations per second, and then 1 iteration will run slower.

So I guess my question is this: is the 60 iterations per second the upper limit for XNA? Is it possible to circumvent it? Should I just ditch XNA altogether?

I really appreciate your time and knowledge. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you specify your platform? Windows, Windows Phone, Xbox 360?

Comment: Sorry, the target platform is Windows.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are having is due to VSync. Disable it in XNA by adding this line to your game's constructor (assuming you have the default `GraphicsDeviceManager graphics`):

```
graphics.SynchronizeWithVerticalRetrace = false;
```

This will allow your game to run "fast as possible". This should be "good enough" for your purposes.

See [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2007/11/23/game-timing-in-xna-game-studio-2-0.aspx) for a description of timing in XNA.

If you wanted to get more fancy: For XNA on Windows I would consider using the Windows event loop and a high resolution timer directly. Note that `Game` in XNA (on Windows and Xbox 360) is entirely optional.

You'd want to move as many slow operations (eg: update and draw) and blocking operations (eg: vsync) off the main thread. Note that input in XNA can only be handled on the main thread. I think you can create the graphics device on a separate thread - although I have never tried it.

You should note that, if you are measuring reaction times, there is lag in between sending a "present" command to the GPU, and that content actually appearing on screen.

Comment: Thanks! This is a lot of help. Don't know how I missed that blog in my research. Disabling VSync seems to have solved the immediate problem, but I'm going to try to put the rendering and updating in another thread as per your suggestion. Is there any way to measure the lag between sending the present command and the actual presentation? If so, I could simply subtract the lag from participant response times.

Comment: Not really, because there is hardware lag to account for too. You can probably measure some of the lag along the pipeline - perhaps everything up until the GPU sends its output to the monitor - but this is outside my area of expertise.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, regardless. I'll look into this.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not expert to XNA development, but, I know I have already similar "problem" in windows phone. (slowly problem).

When you have a lot of treatment, use [multithreading programming,](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ck8bc5c6.aspx),

msdn : "Applications that use multithreading are more responsive to user input because the user interface stays active as processor-intensive tasks execute on separate threads. Multithreading is also useful when you create scalable applications, because you can add threads as the workload increases. "

Hope I help you...

Comment: Multithreading this is a great idea. I'll look into it! Thanks.

Comment: your welcome! in general, when we are lot of treatments, it's solution :p